# WordPress as a data-store?

Tags: plugins, database

I would like to use WordPress to not only run my site, but also to manage users, handle authentication, and read/write content via a client application, but I would like to avoid writing everything from scratch on the PHP-side, as I don't know PHP that well.

Is there a "Services" plugin similar to that in [Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/services), or something else that can give me easy access to using WordPress as a data-store for a client application?

Thanks much in advance for all of your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress uses an [XML-RPC interface](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support)  in which you can define [your own custom methods to it](http://kovshenin.com/archives/custom-xml-rpc-methods-in-wordpress/).

And if server side coding is not your thing , then there are a few plugins that do most of the job for you:

- [WordPress Web Service](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-web-service/)
- [Extended API](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extended-xml-rpc-api/)
- [WP RESTful](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-restful/)

Answer (score 1):

The [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/) also provides a simple, consistent way to retrieve wordpress content. I've used it successfully in a project.